# Copy one value from an list of objects to another list in Java

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a vehcile list, and have different values like vehicle type, name, id etc.

```
List<Vehicle> vehicleList;
```

I want to copy the vehicle name from the above list to a different list something like,

```
List<String> vehicleNameList;
```

How can this be achieved without *manually* iterating the above list and setting it one by one.

Comment: Show us codes please.

Comment: Do you mean without iterating, or without *manually* iterating?

Comment: without manually iterating

Comment: You could save your info as a hashMap using the vehicle name as the key value, then you have direct access to the list of names as the Key set.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to copy the vehicle name from the above list to a different list

and with a condition

> How can this be achieved **without** iterating

In a garbage free world, it is not possible without iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to save like below without iteration?

```
vehicleNameList.add(vehicleList.get(i).getVehicalName());
```

if yes,
I guess it is not possible with existing java api. you need to create such utility for that.

if no,
please be more specific.

Comment: ya that's right Rishi. So it's not possible with the existing api. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

[Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) can help in your case. Below is sample code snippet to convert a List to List.

```
class Vehicle {

private String name;

private String type;

private String registrationNumber;

//getter-setter-constructors
```

}

List transformedList = Lists.transform(vehicles, new Function(){

```
public String apply(Vehicle input) {
    return input.getName();
}
```

});

In addtion to this, you can use [Predicate](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html) filter the objects.